# Saving an Image drawn on a Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I have a simple HTML app where I can draw on a HTML5 canvas. I have a save button where I capture the image using `canvas.todataURL`. When I open this link in a web browser, the full drawing isn't shown -- only a subsection of the drawing. Below is my code. Try it out, it doesn't make sense.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/v0a2Lfsk/1/

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
var mousePressed = false;
var lastX, lastY;
var ctx;

$(window).on('load', function() { 
  canv = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
  canv.width  = $(window).width();
  canv.height = 1000;

  $('#myCanvas').mousedown(function (e) {
    mousePressed = true;
    //Draw(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, false);
    Draw(e.pageX, e.pageY, false);
  });

  $('#myCanvas').mousemove(function (e) {
    if (mousePressed) {
      //Draw(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, true);
      Draw(e.pageX , e.pageY , true);
    }
  });

  $('#myCanvas').mouseup(function (e) {
    mousePressed = false;
  });
  $('#myCanvas').mouseleave(function (e) {
    mousePressed = false;
  });


});

function Draw(x, y, isDown) {
  if (isDown) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
    ctx.lineWidth = $('#selWidth').val();
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  lastX = x; lastY = y;
}

function next(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");  // here is the most important part because if you dont replace you will get a DOM 18 exception.
    console.log(image);

    // html2canvas(document.querySelector("#myCanvas")).then(canvas => {
    //     document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    //     alert("dasds");
    // });

}

function clearArea() {
  // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
}
</script>
<body>
 <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  <div class="controls">     
    <button onclick="javascript:clearArea();return false;">Clear Area</button>
    <button onclick="javascript:next();return false;">Save (Print to Console Log)</button>
    <!-- Line width : <select id="selWidth">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    </select>
    Color : <select id="selColor">
    <option value="black">black</option>
    <option value="blue" selected="selected">blue</option>
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
    <option value="gray">gray</option>
    </select> -->
  </div>

</body>
  <style>
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
#mycanvas
{
  background-color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
*/  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
}
.controls
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color:#2277dd;
  padding:5px;
  margin:2px;
  color:#fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I would highly advise checking out the documentation on that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: @FeaturedSpace Yeah, I did and I followed EXACTLY their code. And still it didn't work.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, I get the full image drawn when I copy the console output and paste into Chrome 74 on my Mac.

Comment: var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); And you're aware that returns a base64 encoded value right?

Comment: What?? No way. I'm also on a Mac and on Chrome 74.

Comment: Did you draw a large image? What happens to me is that I only get the top of the image.

Comment: @FeaturedSpace Yes, I'm aware it's a base64 encoded value. I put that into my Browser URL to see what it looks like

Comment: Try rendering it by actually outputting the HTML? Maybe the browser is interpreting it wrong

Comment: Oh man. I just figured it out. I never pressed the "Show More" button

Comment: Yes. Black square is a screenshot of the result. https://imgur.com/a/TtzZgJL

Comment: If anyone wants to add an answer, I will accept it. I didn't notice the Show More button. I just copied the subsection. AGRGGGRG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you press the "Show More" button in the Console Tab of Developer Tools, otherwise you may copy only part of the output string (as per asdadsads's comment).

In some cases, showing a cut-off base64 string will lead to an error message, while in others (such as yours), a part of the image will be displayed.

Alternatively, just use the "Copy" button, which will copy the entire output.